# Как лучше сверстать блоки в таком хаотичном порядке?

Tags: html, css

Имеется секция, в ней блоки имеют хаотичное расположение (где-то немного выше, где-то сдвинуто по сторонам). Каким методом это можно сверстать более "правильно"?

[image: Скриншот с макета]

Comment: Не такой уж и хаотичный, просто два столбца, внутри которых контент сверху вниз. Как сделать два столбца, в интернете способов навалом, а уж сверху вниз контент автоматически разместится браузером даже без специальной вёрстки

Comment: [grid](https://html5book.ru/css-grid/#:~:text=%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%20(grid%20lines)%20%E2%80%94,%2C%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%B2%20CSS%2D%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5.) вам в помощь.